# array[index].object not working in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am using context API and forex is a state in context API containing array of 21 objects.

example of object is :

```
{
  "Date": "2019-11-09",
  "BaseCurrency": "INR",
  "TargetCurrency": "NPR",
  "BaseValue": "100",
  "TargetBuy": "160.00",
  "TargetSell": "160.15"
}
```

The problem is in 4th line `console.log(date.Date)` and if i remove this line and run this code then 11th line `forex.map(....)` runs fine.

Isn't it the same using .map function in array and using array index to access the object??

Here is the code:

```
  const API = useContext(ExchangeContext);
  const { forex } = API;

  const date = forex[0];
  console.log(date.Date);

  return (
    <table data-vertable='ver1'>
      <thead>
        <TableHead />
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {forex.map((obj) => (
          <TableRow row={obj} key={obj.BaseCurrency} />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
```

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Why do you think `forex` is an array? It if is - why do you think `forest` is not an empty array? "in ReactJS" --- your first 3 lines don't have anything to do with react.

Comment: Did you mean React Context API? Look likes your code not match with the document.

Comment: Ya it's React Context API and i can say that forex is an array cause if i remove `console.log()` line then 10th line `forex.map()` runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your `useContext` call is returning a callback while it waits to get the data from `ExchangeContext` so it doesn't impede the rest of your code from running. Judging from the error you're receiving, it's an error of your `date` variable not being defined rather than it not having the `Date` key from your `forex` array. The reason it works when you remove the `console.log()` is probably because the callback has had enough time to return the data by the time the DOM maps your array but this may possibly break in the future if you use larger data sets. You should probably add some error handling there to map only when the array has data in it. In the meantime you can just move your console.log into a useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof(forex) !== 'undefined' && forex.length) {
    console.log(forex[0].Date)
  }
}, [forex])
```

This way you can guarantee that the `useContext` callback has had enough time to return and that the data loaded into your forex array.